# Full redirect to a log file but remove, on the fly, some text from log

Tags: bash

I'm having this code in bash

```
function main() {
  code here
  echo "data is here"
  code here
  echo "new data is here"
  echo "sensitive data"
  code here
  echo "another data here"
}

main |& tee -a logFile
```

The problem is that I want to remove [ or not to send if possible ] the "sensitive data" from the log

I tried with sed but if I'll change the logFile on the fly, the new data will not be appended anymore

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `main |& sed ... | tee -a logFile`?

Comment: I want "sensitive data" to be displayed to the screen but not logged so I don't know how to do this with sed

Comment: Please edit your question and explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to modify your main function and write the sensible data directly to the terminal:

```sh
function main() {
    # ...
    echo "sensitive data" > /dev/tty
    # ...
}
```

---

An other possibility would be to insert an `awk` script in the pipe, in between `main` and `tee`, for "redirecting" the sensible lines to `/dev/stderr` or `/dev/tty`:

```sh
main |& awk '/sensible data/ { print > "/dev/tty"; next } 1' | tee -a logFile
```

<sup>**edit:** added quotes to `/dev/tty` for making it work with other `awk`s that the GNU one.</sup>

Comment: Can't we skip the printing part altogether `print $0 > /dev/tty;`?

Comment: What do you mean? @AstinGengo wants to display this info in the terminal but not write it in the logfile

Comment: For me sems to work just adding > /dev/tty after the command that I want to be displayed only in terminal but not in log ... only that seems to work without adding awk to the main script

Comment: The `awk` solution is just **An other possibility**, in the case that you don't have control over the `main` script